# ElasticSearch stats API taking long time to response

Tags: performance, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, devops, system-administration

We have an ES cluster at AWS running with the following setup:

*(I know, i need minimum 3 master nodes)*

- 1 Coordinator
- 2 Data nodes
- 1 Master Node

**Data nodes spec:**

- CPU: 8 Cores
- Ram: 20GB
- Disk: 1TB ssd 4000 IOPS

**Problem**:

ES endpoints for Search, Delete, Backup, Cluster Heatlh, Insert are working fine.

Since yesterday some endpoints like `/_cat/indices`, `/_nodes/_local/stats` and etc, started to  take too long to respond(more than 4 minutes) :( and consequently our Kibana is in red state(*Timeout after 30000ms*)

**Useful info:**

All Shards are OK (3500 in total) 
The cluster is in green state 
X-pack disabled 
Average of 1gb/shard 
 
500k document count. 
Requests made by localhost at AWS 
 
CPU, DISK, RAM, IOPS all fine

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT/SOLUTION 1:

After a few days i found out what was the problem, but first a little bit context...

We use Elasticsearch  for storing user audit messages, and mobile error messages, at the first moment (obiviously in a rush to deliver new microservices and remove load from our MongoDB cluster) we designed elasticsearch indices by day, so every day a new indice was created and at the end of the day that indice had arround 6 ~ 9gb of data.
Six months later, almost 180 indices bigger, and 720 primary shards open we bumped into this problem.

Then i did read  this again(the basics!) :
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_basic_concepts.html

After talking to the team responsible for this microservice we redesigned our indices to a monthly index, and guess what? problem solved!

Now our cluster is much faster than before and this simple command saved me some sweet nights of sleep.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html

Thanks!